# How to adjust so the moderator can't add more then 4 inputs for each targetted container

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have input fields which the moderator can create, but I don't want the moderator to be able to add more then 4 input fields for each targetted element. The reason is because I have a grid where there cannot be more then 4 input fields for each targetted container or the next input field will be append underneath it and this will ruin the structure.

The code that appends input fields, but shouldn't append more then 4 for each targetted container:

```
function getAddBtn(target, i) {
    var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-primary',
        'id': 'addBtn'
    }).on('click', function() {
        $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
    console.log(target);
    return addBtn;
}
```

just to be sure I added `getWordPartInput(i)`, this is how the input field is created.

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue) {
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
        'type': 'text',
        'value': cValue,
        'placeholder': 'Syllables',
        'name': 'Syllablescounter[' + SyllablesID++ + ']'
    });
    return wpInput;
}
```

if you need any other code (this was the code I thought was needed) please tell me.

Comment: It's not currently clear what problem you're facing. You don't seem to be making any attempt to limit the number of elements that can be created. Why not try to add that part, then we can help if it doesn't work?

Comment: I did... the part is what you see, the only thing I want to add to this is, how can I put a limit on reproducing the input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the appended syllable class count in the target, in the click event and limit that. Code is:

```
.on('click', function(){
     if($('.syllable',target).length>4)
          return false;
     $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
 })
```